# Magento 2.3.1 installation error with composer

Tags: magento2, composer

I have used PHP 7.2.31 and Magento version 2.3.1 but when Magento 2.3.1 installation with composer getting error like below,

=====================
Your requirements could not be resolved to an install-able set of packages

Problem 1

## Your PHP version  (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement

Any solution on this.

Comment: you try run `composer update` command

Comment: What you see if you run `php -v`